# Order a data frame programmatically using a character vector of column names

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to order a data frame on multiple columns. And the column names are passed through variable, i.e. a character vector.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("b","a","b","a"), var2 = c("l","l","k","k"),
                 var3 = c("t","w","x","t"))

  var1 var2 var3
1    b    l    t
2    a    l    w
3    b    k    x
4    a    k    t
```

Sorting on one column using a variable

```
sortvar <- "var1"
df[order(df[ , sortvar]),]

  var1 var2 var3
2    a    l    w
4    a    k    t
1    b    l    t
3    b    k    x
```

Now, if I want to order by two columns, the above solution does not work.

```
sortvar <- c("var1", "var2")
df[order(df[, sortvar]), ] #does not work
```

I can manually order with column names:

```
df[with(df, order(var1, var2)),]

  var1 var2 var3
4    a    k    t
2    a    l    w
3    b    k    x
1    b    l    t
```

But, how do I order the data frame dynamically on multiple columns using a variable with column names? I am aware of the `plyr` and `dplyr` `arrange` function, but I want to use `base` R here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`order` expects multiple ordering variables as separate arguments, which is unfortunate in your case but suggests a direct solution: use [`do.call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/do.call):

```
df[do.call(order, df[, sortvar]), ]
```

In case you’re unfamiliar with `do.call`: it constructs and executes a call programmatically. The following two statements are equivalent:

```
fun(arg1, arg2, …)
do.call(fun, list(arg1, arg2, …))
```

Comment: Similar variant: `with(mtcars, do.call(order, mget(sortvar)))`

Comment: Is it possible to order one of the variables descending?

Comment: @rmf Yes. If it’s a numeric variable, just negate it. If it’s not numeric, you can use the function `xtfrm` to generate a numeric order from it, and then negate *that*. However, it’s more effort if you still want to order by multiple variables, and only some of these are descending.

Comment: Exactly. I want to use multiple variables and some of them are descending.

Comment: I found a way to do ascending and descending, although it does not work for date/POSIXct variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206129/order-a-r-data-frame-programmatically-using-a-character-vector-of-column-names-w

Comment: @Timo This seems needlessly complicated. R has metaprogramming, you virtually never need to use `parse` (and only rarely `eval`). In fact, the solution doesn’t need either, you can `mapply` your ascending or descending ordering over the sorting variables. And to make it work for dates see my comment above about `xtfrm()`.

Comment: @Timo Apologies, I meant `Map`, not `mapply`. The following code works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74207867/1968

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit awkward, but you can use `do.call()` to pass each of the columns to `order` as a different argument

```
dat[do.call("order", dat[,cols, drop=FALSE]), ]
```

I added `drop=FALSE` just in case `length(cols)==1` where indexing a data.frame would return a vector instead of a list. You can wrap it in a fucntion to make it a bit easier to use

```
order_by_cols <- function(data, cols=1) {
  data[do.call("order", data[, cols, drop=FALSE]), ]
}

order_by_cols(dat, cols)
```

it's a bit easier with dplyr if that's something you might consider

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% arrange(across(all_of(cols)))
dat %>% arrange_at(cols)  # though this method has been superseded by the above line
```